# FetchRequest and NSPredicate issue

Tags: core-data, one-to-many, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I have a 4 Entity One to Many relationship.

Having problem with the fetch and predicates. I am able to fetch the correct 1st entity data (RecordDate) . i use this object self.recordDate. to then fetch the many RecordWorkouts.

my code is below:

```
    self.recordDate = [self.recorddates objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"Date: %@", self.recordDate.date);



    NSFetchRequest *fetchWorkoutRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"RecordWorkout"];
    NSPredicate *predicateWorkout = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"recordDate = %@", self.recordDate];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"recWorkoutName" ascending:YES];
    [fetchWorkoutRequest setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
    [fetchWorkoutRequest setPredicate:predicateWorkout];

    self.recordworkouts = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchWorkoutRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];

    self.recordWorkout = [self.recordworkouts objectAtIndex:0];

    NSLog(@"Workout: %@", self.recordWorkout.recWorkoutName);
```

I manage to fetch the RecordWorkout associated with the RecordDate Entity. This works fine for when there is only one object stored in RecordWorkout.

But When there is more than one stored in RecordWorkout It will fetch them all.

Is it possible to add a secondary NSPredicate within this fetch to for example only fetch the recordWorkout that is equal to workoutLabel.text.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer for anyone who may need it.

Within Predicate you can have two requests:

```
NSPredicate *predicateWorkout = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"recordDate = %@ AND recWorkoutName == %@", self.recordDate, testLabel2.text];
```